# Is there a contradiction about memorial stones

Tags: contradiction, deuteronomy, joshua

In Deuteronomy 16:22 God says not to set up a memorial stone, which He hates.  Yet in numerous other places, e.g., Joshua 4:8 memorial stones are set up, apparently with God's approval.  Is Deut. 16:22 referring only to memorial stones near God's altar?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is part of a larger "problem" in the Bible.  But first, let me observe that the nouns in Deut 16:22 (אֶמַצֵּבָה matstsebah = sacred pillar) and Joshua 4:8 (אֶבֶן eben = a stone) are quite different.  Thus, what Joshua did in Josh 4:8 was not forbidden by Deut 16:22.

**Idols**

The commandment forbidding the making of idols, etc, (Ex 20:4) explicitly forbid anyone making an image of anything on the earth or in heaven or under the earth; yet the sanctuary had many images of angels, plants, animals, etc.  For example:

- the Ark of the covenant had images of angels (Ex 25:17-20)
- The menorah had images of almond buds, blossoms and leaves (Ex 37:17-19)
- Curtains had embroidered angels (Ex 26, 36, 2 Chron 3)

**Pillars**

Deut 16:22 specifically forbids the erection of stone memorials by saying:

> and do not set up for yourselves a **sacred pillar**, which the LORD your
> God hates.  See also Lev 26:1

Further, God instructed the Israelites to smash sacred pillars, Ex 23:24, 34:13, Deut 7:5, 12:3, 2 Kings 18:4, etc.

The operative noun translated "sacred pillar" is, מַצֵּבָה (matstsebah) which occurs often such as:

- Gen 28:18-22 - Jacob sets up a stone pillar at Bethel
- Gen 31:13 - God reminds Jacob of his pillar at Bethel
- Gen 31:45-52 - Jacob sets up another pillar as a witness between himself and Laban
- Gen 35:14 - Jacob erects a pillar at the place God spoke
- Gen 35:20 - Jacob sets up a pillar on Rachel's tomb
- Ex 24:4 - Moses erects 12 pillars

The difference in both cases is rather simple.  Note the very precise instruction in Ex 20:4, 5 -

> You shall not make for yourself an idol in the form of anything in the
> heavens above, on the earth below, or in the waters beneath. **You
> shall not bow down to them or worship them**;

That is, making images and setting up pillars is not the primary problem - it is their worship that is the real problem as perfectly illustrated by the examples above.

Answer (score 4):

No contradiction. - The desecrated Pillar (made by man) in [Deuteronomy 16:22] is not a natural uncut אֶבֶן Even/"Stone" (made by Elohim) found in [Joshua 4:8].

Yehoshua did not use tools on the memorial stones described [Joshua 4:8]. Even all The-Stones הָֽאֲבָנִים "Ha-Avanim" were natural gifts from the riverbed of הַיַּרְדֵּן Ha-Yarden (The-Jordan). Allowing YHVH to provide the memorial by using uncut Stones, Yehoshua performed **the mitsvah of [Exodus 20:22] - "And when you make for Me an altar of stones, you shall not build them of hewn stones, lest you wield your sword upon it and desecrate it." (וְאִם־מִזְבַּ֤ח אֲבָנִים֙ תַּֽעֲשֶׂה־לִּ֔י לֹֽא־תִבְנֶ֥ה אֶתְהֶ֖ן גָּזִ֑ית כִּ֧י חַרְבְּךָ֛ הֵנַ֥פְתָּ עָלֶ֖יהָ וַתְּחַֽלֲלֶֽהָ)**

In contrast we are reminded in [Deuteronomy 16:22] to avoid breaking Exodus 20:22 through the act of designing a מַצֵּבָה Matsevah "Pillar" with tools for memorials like the Obelisk(s) in Egypt.

Notice also how Yaaqov used an uncut Even Stone as a Matsevah Pillar in [Genesis 28:22].